# Next-gen social network built with Python. Possible? Pre-mature? Stupid?

Tags: php, python, performance, scalability, social-networking

I just want to test the waters here. Do you think it would be worth it for a massive-scale social network to be built with Python? Given that Python web development is still fairly experimental at such a large scale, do you think, objectively, that its purported advantages over PHP (high-performance object-oriented execution) would be worth the effort of reinventing a few (or will it be many?) wheels? Using either no framework or a framework like Pyramid (formerly Pylons), not Django.

Comment: Of course you could build it, but would anyone care?

Comment: I have to agree with li.davidm, the technology really doesn't matter, it's all about the user experience and getting a "critical mass" of users.  As evidenced by Facebook, the technology is really a non-issue.

Comment: What this world needs is another social network!

Answer (score 5):

> Given that Python web development is still fairly experimental at such a large scale

This is demonstrably false. <del>Two</del>Three cases in point: [reddit](http://reddit.com), [Disqus](http://disqus.com/), [YouTube](http://youtube.com/).

When you hit “massive scale”, you're going to have problems no matter what language/framework/tools you use (although some will certainly make those problems easier to solve).

The more important question is *will you be able to get to the point where scale matters?*

And that's not a question I, nor anyone else, can answer for certain (although history suggests that the answer is probably “no”)… But, given that any sensible language will scale *pretty well*, I'd submit that you're *more likely* to succeed if you're working with a language and toolkit you're already familiar with. So, if you know PHP, use PHP. If you know Python, use Python.

Comment: +1 Scaling is not language agnostic - it's just hidden in some better than others.

Comment: Don't forget Youtube. 100 billion page views per month, and it's written almost entirely in Python. http://highscalability.com/youtube-architecture http://royal.pingdom.com/2011/02/04/facebook-youtube-our-collective-time-sinks-stats/

Comment: @glowcoder: available libraries and community also make a difference. I believe these were two of the major reasons reddit was re-written in Python from Lisp. Source: http://blog.reddit.com/2005/12/on-lisp.html